# matching pattern to new line

Tags: awk, sed

move  `<acd>` to new line and values after `</acd>` to new line

Input File:

```
abcd<acd>aghjdkadlkh</acd> <bud> dghakj </bud>
```

expected Output:

```
abcd
<acd>
aghjdkadlkh
</acd>
<bud>dghakj</bud>
```

Comment: add an explanation about what you are trying to do... and what did you try to solve it?

Comment: am trying to edit the file as move to a new line once the first matching pattern occurs and move the lines below the second matching pattern to new lines

Comment: Where have the spaces in the last line vanished? Is it intended or a typo?

Comment: Its a typo on the spaces in last line.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` with ERE (`-E`):

```
sed -E 's#</?acd>#\n&\n#g'
```

- `s#</?acd>#\n&\n#g` substitutes `<acd>` and `</acd>` with newlines before and after the pattern

After the operation, to get rid of the leading space of `<bud> dghakj </bud>` removed too, tack a tiny `sed`:

```
sed -E 's#</?acd>#\n&\n#g' ... | sed 's/^ //'
```

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's#</?acd>#\n&\n#g' <<<'abcd<acd>aghjdkadlkh</acd> <bud> dghakj </bud>' 
abcd
<acd>
aghjdkadlkh
</acd>
 <bud> dghakj </bud>

% sed -E 's#</?acd>#\n&\n#g' <<<'abcd<acd>aghjdkadlkh</acd> <bud> dghakj </bud>' | sed 's/^ //'
abcd
<acd>
aghjdkadlkh
</acd>
<bud> dghakj </bud>
```

Comment: `sed -E 's#</?acd>#\n&\n#g; s#\n[[:blank:]]+#\n#g'` would do it and leave any unintended leading spaces untouched as well.

Comment: I tried this code for my xml file and also the above example, it does not make any changes to the input.